# MPI_Bcast send string

Tags: c, string, mpi

i'm having the following problem, i'm trying to send 2 types of data, 1 int, and 2 char, here part of my program

```
#define Send(send_data, count, type, dest, tag) MPI_Send(send_data, count, type, dest, tag, GROUP)
#define Recv(recv_data, count, type, source, tag) MPI_Recv(recv_data, count, type, source, tag, GROUP, &status)
#define Recv(recv_data, count, type, source, tag) MPI_Recv(recv_data, count, type, source, tag, GROUP, &status)
#define Pack(data_in, count_in, type, data_out, count_out, pos) MPI_Pack(data_in, count_in, type, data_out, count_out, pos, GROUP)
#define Unpack(data_out, count_out, pos, data_in, count_in, type) MPI_Unpack(data_out, count_out, pos, data_in, count_in, type, GROUP)
#define Pack_size(count, type, size) MPI_Pack_size(count, type, GROUP, size)
#define MASTER 0


if( rank == 0 ){

    k1 = strlen(prog);
    k2 = strlen(gamesspath);

    for( i = 1; i < proc; i++ ){
      Send(&k1, 1, INT, i, 1);
      Send(&k2, 1, INT, i, 2);
    }
  }
  else{
    Recv(&k1, 1, INT, MASTER, 1);
    Recv(&k2, 1, INT, MASTER, 2);

    gamesspath = malloc( k2 * sizeof(char));
  }

  Pack_size(k1, CHAR, &size1);
  Pack_size(k2, CHAR, &size2);
  Pack_size(1, INT, &size3);

  buffer_size = size1 + size2 + size3;

  buffer = malloc( buffer_size * sizeof(char));

  if( rank == MASTER ){
    pos = 0;

    Pack(prog, k1, CHAR, buffer, buffer_size, &pos);
    Pack(gamesspath, k2, CHAR, buffer, buffer_size, &pos);
    Pack(&nindiv, 1, INT, buffer, buffer_size, &pos);
  }

  Bcast(buffer, buffer_size, PACKED);

  if( rank != MASTER ){
    pos = 0;

    Unpack(buffer, buffer_size, &pos, prog, k1, CHAR);
    Unpack(buffer, buffer_size, &pos, gamesspath, k2, CHAR);
    Unpack(buffer, buffer_size, &pos, &nindiv, 1, INT);
  }

  /*FIM DO ENVIO*/

  printf("PROG = %s, GAMESSPATH = %s, NINDIV = %d - rank %d\n", prog, gamesspath, nindiv, rank);
```

but i'm getting the following result

```
PROG = GAMESS, GAMESSPATH = /usr/local/gamess/rungms1, NINDIV = 10 - rank 1
PROG = GAMESS, GAMESSPATH = /usr/local/gamess/rungms, NINDIV = 10 - rank 0
```

my problem is in GAMESSPATH in rank 1, /usr/local/gamess/rungms1
                               rank 0, /usr/local/gamess/rungms

as can you notice at the end of GAMESS PATH in rank 1, apperas the number 1,
but i can't finde the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in C are terminated with a null byte.  `strlen` returns the length of the string without the null byte.  So when you send the string using MPI, instead of the terminating null byte at the receiver there is some garbage data at the end.

A simple fix would be to add 1 to the value returned by `strlen`.  This does have security implications though if the length value can overflow.  This is probably not a concern in scientific code, but something to be aware of.

Also, why do you need to pack the buffers?  It looks like these strings are in contiguous storage.  You also don't really need to send the length: just tell the receiver to receive up to the maximum buffer size, and use the actual length at the sender.

Comment: i calculate exact pack_size to avoid memory problems, because the program allocate a large amount of memory at the start, and the reason to pack data is just to minimize the comunication betwin rank's. Edit: only the MASTER rank know the size of prog, and gamesspath, then i need to send to other ranks

Comment: You are right, for larger messages it makes sense to know the size.  For just a single path though you could simply call `MPI_Recv` with a length of `MAX_PATH`, to receive a message up to that length.  At the sender you would call `MPI_Send` with the actual length.  When the receiver gets the message, it can use `MPI_Get_count` to find the actual length of the message if needed.

Comment: Also, `MPI_Pack` introduces an extra memory copy.  This is a performance hit, and is best avoided unless absolutely necessary.  If your data structures are more complex than simple arrays, you could try to describe the structures using MPI datatypes.